# Replace string with most frequent fuzzy match

Tags: r, stringdist

I have a dataframe of unstructured names, and I want to create a 'master' list of the cleaned name in one column with all the variants in another column. I am using the `stringdist` package. Below is a small example:

```r
library(dplyr) # for pipes 
library(tidyr) # for expand_grid()
library(stringdist) 

words <- c("dog","dot","don","con","cry","croak","cat","dogg", "dogy", "dog", "cat", "dog")
# compare everything to everything 
words_df <- expand_grid(raw = words, clean = words) %>%
    mutate(dist = stringdist(raw, clean, method = "jw") %>% 
    # compute word frequency 
    group_by(clean) %>%
    mutate(count = n()) %>%
filter(dist < 0.3)
```

This results in a df with the distance and word counts for all similar enough combinations:

```
|raw |clean |      dist| count|
|:---|:-----|---------:|-----:|
|dog |dog   | 0.0000000|    36|
|dog |dot   | 0.2222222|    12|
|dog |don   | 0.2222222|    12|
|dog |dogg  | 0.0833333|    12|
|dog |dogy  | 0.0833333|    12|
|dog |dog   | 0.0000000|    36|
|dog |dog   | 0.0000000|    36|
|dot |dog   | 0.2222222|    36|
|dot |dot   | 0.0000000|    12|
|dot |don   | 0.2222222|    12|
```

You can see that in the `clean` column I have two entries for "dog" and "dogg", which I would want to collapse into one entry (dog) because the string "dog" appears more often.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```r
dict <- words_df %>%
    mutate(clean_new = ifelse(dist < 0.085, words_df[which.max(words_df$count)][[1]][1], clean))
```

Which results in:

```
|raw |clean |      dist| count|clean_new |
|:---|:-----|---------:|-----:|:---------|
|dog |dog   | 0.0000000|    36|NA        |
|dog |dot   | 0.2222222|    12|dot       |
|dog |don   | 0.2222222|    12|don       |
|dog |con   | 0.4444444|    12|con       |
|dog |cry   | 1.0000000|    12|cry       |
|dog |croak | 0.4888889|    12|croak     |
|dog |cat   | 1.0000000|    24|cat       |
|dog |dogg  | 0.0833333|    12|NA        |
|dog |dogy  | 0.0833333|    12|NA        |
|dog |dog   | 0.0000000|    36|NA        |
```

Essentially what I want to create is a dictionary of all variants of the word, based on frequency of the closest word match.

Thanks all!

Comment: Just to point out for the future, this code will be very inefficient if you are scaling it up to a very long list of words. If there are many repeats it would calculate the distance scores of identical word pairs redundantly. A more efficient solution would be to calculate the pairwise distances on `unique(words)` and tabulate the counts of each word separately, then combine the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `dplyr` pipe statement will return a data frame with 9 rows, one for each of the unique elements in your original `words` vector. First we `group_by` the `raw` column which creates a group for each unique word, then `filter` by your distance threshold, then find the corresponding word in `clean` with the highest frequency in the original dataset. In your example all words match themselves except for the two variants of "dog."

#### Code

```
words_df %>%
  group_by(raw) %>%
  filter(dist < 0.085) %>%
  summarize(clean = clean[which.max(count)])
```

#### Output

```
# A tibble: 9 x 2
  raw   clean
  <chr> <chr>
1 cat   cat  
2 con   con  
3 croak croak
4 cry   cry  
5 dog   dog  
6 dogg  dog  
7 dogy  dog  
8 don   don  
9 dot   dot
```